# Running Drupal code inspections via PHP Storm returns incorrect results

Tags: 8

When I run PHP Code Sniffer inspections in PHP Storm (latest version) for Drupal code using the latest Drupal coding standards (from the Coder module), I get incorrect results. Running the inspections manually on the command line seems to return the proper results. I don't know why.

Here's the output of running phpcs manually against this test file from the CAS module:

```
/Users/bosborne/.composer/vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=/Users/bosborne/.composer/vendor/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer/Drupal tests/src/Unit/Subscriber/CasSubscriberTest.php

FILE: ...ules/contrib/cas/tests/src/Unit/Subscriber/CasSubscriberTest.php
----------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 11 ERRORS AND 4 WARNINGS AFFECTING 15 LINES
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  16 | WARNING | [x] Unused use statement
  99 | ERROR   | [x] Expected "MockCondition" but found
     |         |     "MockCondition;" for @var tag in member variable
     |         |     comment
 131 | ERROR   | [x] Array indentation error, expected 6 spaces but
     |         |     found 8
 132 | ERROR   | [x] Array indentation error, expected 6 spaces but
     |         |     found 8
 133 | ERROR   | [x] Array indentation error, expected 6 spaces but
     |         |     found 8
 134 | ERROR   | [x] Array indentation error, expected 6 spaces but
     |         |     found 8
 135 | WARNING | [x] A comma should follow the last multiline array
     |         |     item. Found: ]
 148 | ERROR   | [x] There should be no white space after an opening
     |         |     "["
 149 | WARNING | [x] A comma should follow the last multiline array
     |         |     item. Found: ]
 162 | ERROR   | [x] There should be no white space after an opening
     |         |     "["
 163 | WARNING | [x] A comma should follow the last multiline array
     |         |     item. Found: ]
 177 | ERROR   | [x] Object operator not indented correctly; expected
     |         |     6 spaces but found 35
 193 | ERROR   | [x] Object operator not indented correctly; expected
     |         |     6 spaces but found 28
 194 | ERROR   | [ ] If the line declaring an array spans longer than
     |         |     80 characters, each element should be broken
     |         |     into its own line
 564 | ERROR   | [x] Inline comments must start with a capital letter
----------------------------------------------------------------------
PHPCBF CAN FIX THE 14 MARKED SNIFF VIOLATIONS AUTOMATICALLY
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Lots of errors and warnings!

But when I configure my PHP Storm (latest version) to run the inspections on the same file, I get just two weak warnings, and the filedoc one it complains about is wrong (file docs are not required on namespaced files).

[image]

So something is out of wack here, but for the life of me I cannot figure out why PHP Storm is returning the wrong output.

Environment info:

- Using version 8.x-2.9 of the Coder module
- Using version 2.7 of phpcs
- Code Sniffer is setup in PHP Storm using the same exact path that I use when running the command manually (see config image below)
- Inspections are setup in PHP Storm to use "Custom" inspections and I proide the path to the Drupal coding standards (the same path that I use when running it manually)

[image]

[image]

**EDIT:** I also filed an issue with PHP Storm directly: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-34029

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about PHPStorm and not about Drupal. PHPStorm has their own issue tracker where this issue needs to get reported to, not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - Embarrassingly enough, this was indeed "user error". The path to the coding standard that PHP Storm was using was indeed slightly different than the path I thought it was using. The paths were quite similar so I didn't catch it during my own reviews.

What helped is that you can configure PHP Storm to output the exact command it runs in the debug log by doing the following: Open Help > Debug Log Settings and add there `com.jetbrains.php`. Then run the inspection and look at the debug log.